# WebApi doesnt serialize null fields

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I've got the following following command in my web api:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
    MyDBContext.DB.Database.SqlQuery<MyCustomerClass>("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER").ToList());
```

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([CustomerID] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
      ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I have found that when requesting data from the webApi, if the fields are `null` then the returning JSON result doesn't include that field in the return result. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the fix was to specify the following in the json formatter serializer settings:

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() 
{ 
   NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's expected behavior. At least in terms of JSON. I can't speak much about WebAPI, since I haven't used it. In a project of mine that uses JSON, if I were to issue the following code:

```
# Package our response into an array... 
$response = array("type"=>"remove_from_distribution_list","results");                   

# And send it back to XMLHttpRequest object encoded...       
echo json_encode($response);
```

with **results** having no value, results would still be passed along. There would just be no value passed alongside it.