# WebAPI not returning JSON for INT when value is zero

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have this class, as a cut down version:

```
public class SportTableRow
{
    public Int32 Won { get; set; }
    public Int32 Lost { get; set; }
    public Int32 Drawn { get; set; }
    public Int32 For { get; set; }
}
```

When I make a call to the Data via the WebAPI, it looks like this (again cut down)...

```
public List<SportTableRow> Get()
        {
            var options = ....
            var sport = ....
            var locationCode = ...

            return SportManager.GetOverallTable(sport, options, 
                      locationCode).TableRows;
        }
```

When I inspect the returned data in debugger, you can see the properties in the list...

[image]

But, when I call via fiddler, you can see that a few properties are missing...

[image]

...and it seems to be any `Int`'s that are 0, and `bool`'s which are false etc.

Do I need to set anything on the actual class, or something in the JSON serializer?

Comment: @bump He did not ask for that.

Comment: @user2674389 He didn't ask how to get the Json to work?

Comment: @bump He asked why there are properties missing in his resulting JSON. Please read the whole question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The JSON serializer [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is set by default to exclude properties that are set to default values. For Example, `boolean=false`, `int=0`, `int?=null`, `object=null`, etc. *will be excluded from the resulting JSON*. The intention is to minimize bandwidth.

You can change this behavior by changing the settings:

```
    System.Web.Http
              .GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
              .Formatters
              .JsonFormatter
              .SerializerSettings
              .DefaultValueHandling 
                             = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;
```

Best add this line in the `Global.asax` file. But note: This will just add bandwidth with no real benefit, especially if you control the client side too

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I needed to update the WebAPI via NuGet too, so this worked (worth reading this too, in my case) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999165/cant-make-mvc4-webapi-include-null-fields-in-json

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that bug. Thanks for letting me know!